# Objective C / Sprite Kit: How do I access variables stored in UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I am very new to iOS development.

Since I wanted to integrate iAd banners in the menu screen section of my app, I wrote the code

```
[super viewDidLoad];
BOOL iAdBanner = self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

into the UIViewController.m file.

Now my question is, how can I access my variable "iAdBanner" in MyScene.h ?

I tried using

```
#import "DSViewController.m"
```

but apparently it's not used like that...

Comment: I suggest learning some Objective-C and going through a few tutorial programs.  That should clear up the basics of how programs are structured.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to import the view controller's header in your scene, but you need to get a reference to that view controller before you can access any of its properties. From within your SKScene subclass, you can access the view controller's `canDisplayBannerAds` property like this:

```
DSViewController *viewController = (DSViewController *)self.scene.view.window.rootViewController;
BOOL iAds = viewController.canDisplayBannerAds;
```